# Execute a Jenkins pipeline on remote host without a slave

Tags: jenkins, triggers, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, remote-server

My Jenkins is on host1 and I wish to trigger ansible which is on host2 using Jenkins pipeline. This can be done by creating a slave node on host2 and specifying `agent` in Jenkins pipeline.

However, I do not have a Jenkins slave on host2.

Instead, Jenkins has connectivity to host2 by means of `Server Groups Center` which can be found under `Jenkins Global Configuration`

Do I need a Jenkins slave on host2 ? If not, then how can I use `Server Groups Center` in Jenkins pipeline to trigger Ansible on host2? Sample code please…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need a Jenkins slave on host2?

No, if you have Linux on `host2`: you can simply run any command over SSH.

> How can I use Server Groups Center in Jenkins pipeline to trigger Ansible on host2?

`Server Groups Center` block comes from [SSH2 Easy plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh2easy/), which is very old and [doesn't support](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh2easy-plugin/issues/9) Jenkins pipeline. So you can't use information from that block of settings in your pipeline.

But there are other plugins for SSH; try [Publish over SSH](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/) plugin for example. This plugin adds `Publish over SSH` block to `Jenkins Global Configuration`, where you can specify `host2` connection parameters.

And then you can write pipeline step as follows (`{HOST2}` is the name of `host2` that you type in `Publish over SSH` block in `Jenkins Global Configuration`):

```
steps {
    sshPublisher \
        failOnError: true, \
        publishers: [ \
            sshPublisherDesc( \
                configName: "{HOST2}", \
                transfers: [ \
                    sshTransfer (execCommand: "ansible -m ping all -i inventory_file", execTimeout: 120000) \
                ] \
            ) \
        ]
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks @Alexey Prudnikov for the detailed answer.